# Open Visual Studio solutions and files with command in C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, command

I am making a C++ 2D game engine and I've embedded c# for scripting. What I am trying to do now is opening a c# script with the engine using the `system();`.

Imagine that the working directory has two files: mySolution.sln and testScript.cs

If I run `system("mySolution.sln");` it will open the solution, that's fine. But if I do it again, it will open the solution again so I will have 2 solutions. How can I just focus the solution the second time? I do not want to open another. And what do I have to do to open the solution with a specific file?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the people downvoting can explain how the question can be improved?

Comment: Can this be done with tracking the process ID to check if Visual Studio is already running?

Comment: Could you please tell us whether you want to open the mySolution.sln and testScript.cs in the same visual studio with command? How do you use the `system("mySolution.sln");` to open the solution? Could you please provide the detailed steps?

Comment: I think there is no more to say. I just want to open the visual studio with a file selected with a command using system(), but before this check if this is already opened